# How to Create a new Sheet in google spreadsheet with no gridlines

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to create a sheet with google spreadsheet script, with no gridlines, and I am using:

```
NewSheet=ss.insertSheet(SheetName);
```

But, the default seens to be "with gridlines", so I tried:

```
NewSheet=ss.insertSheet(SheetName, ss.getNumSheets() , {template:OtherSheet} );
```

It works, but the new sheet carry all other contents, and I need to remove everything. Is there any way to create a new sheet and turn off gridlines ?

Comment: I can't find any way around that - there just isn't much programmatic control over the look of sheets. How about making a blank template sheet, and otherwise doing what you're doing? That way, no need to blank things out. Also, you could hide the sheet to avoid messing it up.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the Google Apps Script API supports it at present time.

As you suggested, cloning an existing sheet and removing everything from it should do the trick.